# Prevent Autofilter Criteria from changing from string to date

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have some data with 5000 rows, one of the columns represents the size of a group.  They are all text with ranges of values like:

```
"0 - 4", "5 - 9", "10 - 49", "50 - 99", "100 - 249", "250 or more"
```

These are all stored as text.

I have written some VBA to use autofilter to display everything but the item I want so that the other rows can be deleted.  Like:

```
activesheet.range("a1:a5000").autofilter field:=1, criteria1:="<>" & strValue
```

`strValue` is populated with each value and is declared as a string.

- It all works fine, except when it gets to `"10 - 49"`.  It will not
  exclude `"10 - 49"` when displayed.
- I can replicate the behavior manually -- if I go to the autofilter
  pulldown for the column, select Text `Filters>Does Not Equal`, and
  then choose the pulldown choice for `"10 - 49"` (or just type it) and
  hit `OK`, it will not apply.  It still shows the 10 - 49 rows.
- When I go back into the Text `Filters>Custom` Filter it shows does
  not equal `18172`.

> `18172` is the date value for `"Oct-1949"`.

Even if I explicitly set the code to:

```
activesheet.range("a1:a5000").autofilter field:=1, criteria1:="<>10 - 49"
```

It converts the 10 - 49 to the date value.  It you record a macro and do it manually via the autofilter pulldown, it will show criteria1 as `"<>Oct-1949"` in the recorded code.

I got it to work by using `criteria1:="<>*" & strValue`, but that happens to work with this data, but might not work if I had different values with `10 - 49` in it.

So my question is, is there anyway to prevent it from converting

```
"<>10 - 49"
```

to

```
"<>Oct-1949"
```

Does it need to be escaped somehow to tell it to treat that as true text?  Or is this just a quirk of Excel?  It works with `criteria1:="=10 - 49"` (even when recording the macro).

It happens in **Excel 2010, 2013 and 2016.**

Comment: Does the column have text format?

Answer (score 0):

You'd think there'd be a way, especially with the spaces in `10 - 49`.
Until/unless someone comes up with the answer, you can try this.

- create a unique list of all the entries in the column to be filtered
- exclude `strvalue` from that list
- Use that unique list to select all the entries in the column except for `strValue`

Below is just an example with a single value for `strValue`.  You should be able to use the principle to apply the technique in other ways.

For example, populate the collection with the entire list, and then populate `arrVals` with all except `strValue` might be better for a scenario where you are populating `strValue` with different values

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub filterTest()
    Dim R As Range, WS As Worksheet
    Const strValue As String = "10 - 49" 'value to exclude
    Dim colVals As Collection, vVals As Variant
    Dim arrVals() As String, I As Long

Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    Set R = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
End With

WS.ShowAllData

'Get list of values to include
Set colVals = New Collection

'read the range into variant array for speed of execution
vVals = R.Offset(1, 0).Resize(R.Rows.Count - 1)

On Error Resume Next 'to skip the duplicates
    For I = 1 To UBound(vVals, 1)
        If Not vVals(I, 1) = strValue Then 'exclude if strValue
            colVals.Add vVals(I, 1), vVals(I, 1)
        End If
    Next I
On Error GoTo 0

ReDim arrVals(1 To colVals.Count)
For I = 1 To colVals.Count
    arrVals(I) = colVals(I)
Next I

R.AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=arrVals, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```